# How to search a string in files partially matching "name"

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm looking for a class which is defined in a Koin module file somewhere in my project. The filenames of all those Koin modules are "*Module.kt".

I could do cmd+shift+F to search for "TheClass" everywhere, but that gives me too many results and I don't want to go through all of them manually. I'd like to only search in files with the above mentioned filename pattern.

Another thing I could do is to use alt+F7 or cmd+B on the TheClass itself to see its usages, but again that leads to too many results.

Is there a way (using Android Studio) to search smarter for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that when using "Find in Path" with cmd+shift+F you can put more in the file mask than just "*.kt". I've changed the file mask to "*Module.kt" and got the desired result.